# Copy Postgres-Table with Python (sqlalchemy) but can't change the target schema

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to copy a table from one postgres database (dss_test) to another (dss_prod) using the Python module sqlalchemy. I want to copy the metadata too (e. g. datatypes, constraints etc.).

I created two engines, one for the source database and one for the target database.

```
src_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://'+authTokens[0]+':'+authTokens[2]+'@localhost:5432/dss_test', echo=True)
trg_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://'+authTokens[0]+':'+authTokens[2]+'@localhost:5432/dss_prod', echo=True)
```

After that I catch the metadata from the table in the source database...

```
meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=src_engine)
table = sqlalchemy.Table('test_table', meta, schema='public', autoload=True)
```

...and create the new table in the target database.

```
table.metadata.create_all(trg_engine)
```

That works fine so far!

The problem is, that the source table is in the schema 'public' but the target should be in the schema 'nonpublic'. If I execute my code the new table is also in the schema 'public'.

Can I change the target schema?

Possible solutions to my problem may involve the usage of another module (e. g. psycopg2 etc.)

Take into consideration, that I have rights to read and write in the source database everywhere but in the target database only in the schema 'nonpublic'

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I don't know `SQLAlchemy`  well enough, but could you not do: `table.schema='nonpublic'` just before the `table.metadata.create_all(trg_engine)`? Or why not  just do: `table = sqlalchemy.Table('test_table', meta, schema='nonpublic', autoload=True)`?

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it is to easy.
table.schema='nonpublic' worked.